# how to handle this InputMismatchException?

Tags: java, inputmismatchexception

In the code below I'm getting `InputMismatchException` at line 80 even before I'm giving the input. Why is this?

```
try {
    loop:while(true)
    {
        choice=sc.nextInt();
        switch (choice) {
            case 1: 
                term=3;
                break loop;
            case 2:
                term=6;
                break loop;
            default:
                System.out.println("Invalid Input.. Enter again");
                choice=sc.nextInt();
        }
    } 
}
catch (InputMismatchException e2) {
    System.out.println("Wrong Format!! Enter a number");
    choice=sc.nextInt();  //line 80
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consume the end of line:

```
catch (InputMismatchException e2) {
    System.out.println("Wrong Format!! Enter a number");
    sc.nextLine(); // add this
    choice=sc.nextInt();  //line 80
}
```

In addition, you probably shouldn't have two `choice=sc.nextInt();` in your loop.

And you want to put the try-catch inside the loop, in order to stay in the loop after the exception is caught.